# How can a designer with no MVC experience design a web app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, django

I worked with a freelance designer to create a static version of an application. After integrating it in with my back end code (Django), the only option I see for him to continue working on it is to have him copy the development environment. This isn't an option with this designer - he isn't willing to work with back end code.

My first option is to get rid of him and get a more competent designer, but I'm not to happy about doing that. Are there any tools that I can leverage to allow him to easily contribute to front end code (HTML/CSS).

Everything is nicely packaged (virtualenv + requirements make it a breeze to set up), but setting up the database might be pretty rough for someone with only a knowledge of HTML/CSS. I was thinking about serving the website from my computer from a common Dropbox folder - I'm pretty sure he wouldn't need restart the server to see any changes in HTML/CSS (correct me if I'm wrong!). Are there any big flaws with this? Or better yet - are there elegant solutions out there for this problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:** To make it explicitly clear.

1.) I am the backend developer.

2.) The designer wrote all of the front end code, I want him to continue.

3.) All front end code is now rendered by the backend I wrote, hence, the designer/front end developer will need to install the development environment (which is what I am looking for solutions to by asking this question).

Comment: So..umm..who's doing the backend?

Comment: I am doing the backend, while I integrated the frontend with the backend locally, I don't see a way for him to continue working on the front end. Continual integration on my part is not an option - it's pretty wasteful on time when ideally the designer can contribute directly to a live frontend code base.

Comment: As a formally trained designer and self-taught coder, I would recommend pulling in someone else if your *design*er isn't willing, or simply doesn't want to write front-end code. A lot of designers still only do design and no code. Formally trained designers who are also highly competent coders are close to unicorns.

Comment: @Brandon - I think that is what I am going to have to do. He is writing front end code (HTML,CSS, Javascript), but said has not experience setting up development environments. Its frustrating because it would only take a good hour or two but he won't do it. Maybe if I keep looking I will find a tool that will let him work on the front end without requiring any set up.

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan - I don't get why you are so confused. I said in my question and in my response to your message that I am doing the backend code myself. I don't need a "real serving environment" - I already have one set up. I need a development environment for a designer. When I said a "common Dropbox folder" I meant a "common Dropbox folder" as a way to share code. With that said - I am most likely going to look for someone else, but your comment is completely missing the point.

Comment: Apologies.Have removed that comment.

Comment: That designer is simply as willing to work in HTML as I am in .NET :) A lot of designers I've worked with in the past simply have no desire to write code, of any kind whatsoever. So don't take too much offense to it. Sometimes working relationships just don't work out, no pun intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox is no way to share and version code. Take a look at [Git](http://git-scm.com/) for the code sharing and versioning (there's a nice GUI for every OS, so he'll probably manage). You can outline the steps for him to deploy it to his own system (e.g. git clone, rake db:create, rake db:migrate, rails s) in some kind of document and you'll both be up and running.

If you really want to make it easy for him, set up a small webserver on which you clone the code, so he can work there, immediately see the changes and after a good day's work, you can merge your efforts with his.

Comment: I wholeheartedly second the notion of using Git, SVN or anything else besides Dropbox for sharing versioned code.

Comment: I am already using git, I just didn't know if it would be a good idea to use it with a designer who is not familiar with it. Thanks for the advice - I think showing him the basics of project management / git is a good idea if he is willing to learn.

Comment: And if he's not, the second suggestion works as well. I've used that method on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the django setup for him surely. It hardly takes half an hour.

And show him the location of html/css/js and all he needs to do is make changes there and hard refresh the web page.

For code sharing, use any software versioning system (svn, git etc.)

Teach him the basic processes: Pull latest code and commit/push his own.